# Multiple problems setting up Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.03 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I´m already trying to install Ubuntu next to Windows 10 for dual boot for 3 days. Now I´m really stuck and kinda frustrated, hope you guys can help me!

**Current status:**

1. Coming from Ubuntu, installed Windows 10
2. applied boot-repair with Live-USB to get back Grub2, did not work (still Win booting)
3. Installed "EasyBCD" to set up dual boot. No success.

Was about trying to install Ubuntu *AFTER* Windows but Ubuntu installer does not regocnize my Windows Installation/Windows Bootloader. By this I mean that for the Ubuntu Installer, the disk with its partitions is completly empty.

---

I read nearly everything that´s out there in the Web to solve these problems for the points mentioned.

- Trying to let Ubuntu installer regocnize Windows OS
- Easy BCD Setup
- Boot-repair for Grub

---

**Screenshots**
[image: Disks and Partitions]

On "Datenträger 1" (EVO 850 SSD) Windows 10 is installed on the 151 GB Partition. Linux is installed on the 62 GB Partition with the SWAP being the 7,8 GB Partition. 
"Datenträger 0" is just another HDD with Data.

---

If there´s any additional information you need just mention it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem today on my own.

Problem was that Windows was installed in *"BIOS" Mode with MBR-Partition Tables*.

In order to work with Ubuntu for dual boot, Windows has to be installed in *"UEFI" Mode with GPT Tables*.

After doing that, Windows bootloader is recognized by Ubuntu installer and everything works fine.